# Can I check online if the UK Visa is approved?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I just got an Email yesterday advising that the decision has been made and I should wait since I have to collect it from the UK application centre.  Is it possible to just check online about the decision.

Answer (score 4):

No. The only way to find out is to collect your decision letter.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk/getting-a-decision-on-your-application:

> Getting a decision on your application
>
> - You’ll get a letter with the result of your application. The letter will explain what you need to do next.